# gmail is disabling imap?

Tags: node.js, gmail, imap

I have recently came through an article which states that the IMAP is going to be disabled after September 2024. And Google gonna use Oauth for more protection for third party apps. As said IMAP will be disabled right ?.and if it is so will the developers or coders are able to access user's Gmail for management (like it used to be in IMAP)?

[image]
the above image is from https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2023/09/winding-down-google-sync-and-less-secure-apps-support.html

i just wanted to know that if we can able to use IMAP and access the user's emails like the now or it will be definitely changed. for protection Gmail is going to make developers to not access mails of users?

Answer (score 0):

No.

IMAP is not being disabled. What's being disabled is a couple of IMAP-related settings. You'll be constrained to the default values (effectively "no plaintext passwords").

Comment: So, IMAP will stop working with less secure apps, and also with app password right ? The only way to use IMAP will be trough the oAuth authentication ?

Comment: I don't know whether oauth will be the *only* way. It's a good way though.